# Modifying bash script to take each line in a file and execute command

Tags: mysql, bash, sh

I need to modify a bash script to to take each line in a file and execute command. I currently have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    echo "Lipsa IP";
    exit;
fi
i=1
ip=$1
while [ $i -le `wc -l pass_file | awk '{print $1}'` ] ; do
    if [ -n "$ip" ]; then
        rand=`head -$i pass_file | tail -1`
        user=`echo $rand | awk '{print $1}'`
        pass=`echo $rand | awk '{print $2}'`

        CMD=`ps -eaf | grep -c mysql`

        if [ "$CMD" -lt "50" ]; then
            ./mysql $ip $user $pass &
        else
            sleep 15
        fi
        i=`expr $i + 1`
    fi
done
```

The password file is in format and name pfile:

```
username password
```

The intranet hosts file is in this format (line-by-line) and name hlist:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do which you are not already doing. Do you want to use the ip number file in some fashion?

Anyway, the way you extract the username and password from the password file is unnecessarily complicated (to put it politely); you can iterate over the lines in a file in a much simpler fashion. Instead of:

```
while [ $i -le `wc -l pass_file | awk '{print $1}'` ] ; do
  rand=`head -$i pass_file | tail -1`
  user=`echo $rand | awk '{print $1}'`
  pass=`echo $rand | awk '{print $2}'`
  # ...
  i=`expr $i + 1`
fi
```

Just use the bash (Posix) read command:

```
while read -r user pass __; do
  # ...
done < pass_file
```

(The `__` is in case there is a line in the pass_file with more than two values; the last variable name in the `read` command receives "the rest of the line").

Answer (score 0):

I searched the web again and found a cleaner code which I adapted to suit my needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read ip
do
if [ -n "$ip" ]
then
  while read user pass
  do
     CMD=`ps -eaf | grep -c mysql`
     if [ "$CMD" -gt "50" ]
     then
        sleep 15
     fi
     ./mysql $ip $user $pass &
  done < pass_file
fi
  done < host_file
```